# symfony pagination multiple in same page

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

I would add several pagination button on the same page. Here is my page:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV7xy.jpg]

Currently I use knppaginator like this:

```
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $demandes,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        5
    );
```

I try to use knppaginator in this way:

```
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $demandes,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        5
    );
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $paginationF = $paginator->paginate(
        $forumTopics,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        5
    );
```

But it does not work. When I change page with one it changes the page of the other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is because you use same "page" parameter for both paginations. Try this

```
$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $demandes,
    $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
    5
);

$paginationF = $paginator->paginate(
        $forumTopics,
        $request->query->getInt('otherPage', 1),
        5,
       ['pageParameterName' => 'otherPage']
    );
```

Comment: how about the sort?

Comment: @iamjc015 available options are at [`KnpPager`](https://github.com/KnpLabs/knp-components/blob/master/doc/pager/config.md) use `'sortFieldParameterName' => 'otherSort'`.

Comment: Does it works for you ? I did the same but when I add my 2 paginations in the `return $this->render('my-view.html.twig')` I have a Symfony error `undefined variable pagination1` whereas it exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, per default, all services are shared. This means that each time you retrieve the service, you'll get the *same* instance — [see reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html).

But that can be changed in the definition of your service if you flag it as not shared, as the documentation is proposing it:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.some_not_shared_service:
        class: ...
        shared: false
        # ...
```

In you case your service is called `knp_paginator` and coming from their bundle.

So you just have to change your own `app/config/services.yml` to make their service non shared:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    knp_paginator:
        shared: false
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I use it in my case?

Comment: You should have somewhere a definition of your service: ```knp_paginator``` there, you should be able to add that ```shared: false``` parameter

Comment: $paginator  = $this->get('app.some_not_shared_service');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $demandes,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            5
        );
        $paginator  = $this->get('app.some_not_shared_service');
        $paginationF = $paginator->paginate(
            $forumTopics,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            1
        );